# Internet disconnect/connect each 10 seconds on vmware player

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware-player

My host is Ubuntu 16. I've installed VMPlayer and then installed same Ubuntu 16 as virtual machine.

Everything is fine except internet.. every 10-20 seconds virtual machine get disconnected and then connected.

Network settings are static on the host (IP, Mask, Gateway). On the virtual machine settings I've choose NAT: Used to share the host's IP and DHCP on the network settings.

It is very annoying this .. I can't even install new packages with `apt-get`.

Please any help with how to fix this is appreciated.

Note: I've tried to Bridge the network-> no internet at all. Then I've tried NAT with manual IP, Mask, Gateway adding -> no internet.

Comment: I've had very similar experiences. Thought it was just something wrong with my setup. I see this is 'an issue'. Not completely sure, I think it's happening only with Linux guests, and Windows guests are stable. Haven't really 'studied' the issue, but I think this is what I've observed. Following to see if anyone knows a fix